# after compiling solidity contract i receive data location must be "storage" or "memory" error

Tags: storage, solidity

This code is copy and pasted from a solidity tutorial and i get the error message in the screen shot when compiling. After some searching i think i'm supposed to be typing "storage" somewhere in the function but not sure where.

Do i need to use storage instead of memory because the data is being permanently stored in the 'name' and 'dna' variables? Where does storage need to by typed?

[image: solidity code]

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is declare the `_name` parameter like this `string memory _name`, and for any other `string` parameters you may use. This was introduced probably in a later compiler version than the one that was used for the tutorial you followed.

Comment: for the later solidity version the memory and storage is replaced by calldata